# Regular expression for Password Requirements for PCI Compliance

Tags: regex, passwords

Here are password requirements for PCI compliance:

- Must contain at least one upper case letter
- Must contain at least one lower case letter
- Must contain at least one number
- Must contain at least one special character such as #, !, ?, ^, or @.

Please tell me how to create such regulat expressions? I can`t figure out how to do it

Comment: use `lookaheads` if present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it as a single regex. There's no need to do it in a single regex, and it will be easier to change the rules, and be much easier to read, if you just make multiple regex checks.

If you were doing this in Perl, for example, you'd just do

```
my $ok =
    ($pw =~ /[a-z]/) &&  # Has at least one lowercase char
    ($pw =~ /[A-Z]/) &&  # Has at least one uppercase char
    ($pw =~ /\d/)    &&  # Has at least one digit
    ($pw =~ /[#!?^@]);   # Has punctuation
```

That is far easier to read later on when you have to maintain the code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#\!\?\^@])$
```

the special characters are individually specified

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*\d.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[#\!\?\^@].*$
```

Simply this should do it for you.